# IdUDPServer sending header checksum as 0x00

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-xe3

I am making a simple UDP P2P Chat Program with a well known server. 
The client's send and recieve data from server and clients through a single IdUDPServer.

The clients as of now can login and logout i.e. they can send data to the server.
Whenever the server sends any data it gets dropped at the NIC side of the node as the embedded ip header checksum is 0x00 as notified by wireshark.

#### IdUDPServer Settings (Client/Server)

Active : True

Bindings :

Broadcast : False

BufferSize : 8192

DefaultPort : 10000

IPVersion : Id_IPv4

ThreadedEvent : False

#### Command Used

only one command is used within

UDPServer.SendBuffer ( ED_Host.Text, StrToInt ( ED_Port.Text ), Buffer );

A similar configuration is working perfectly in another program of mine.

Comment: `SendBuffer()` merely passes the data as-is to the socket API `sendto()` function, so it is the OS/NIC that generates the checksum, not Indy.

Comment: ok... so what can i check to get it working again? Ports are open and the firewalls are off still the checksum...

Comment: Most NICs will perform checksum validation and generation these days instead of the os network stack. This is to improve performance and is known as checksum offloading. As such wiresshark will report the fact the checksum is missing as an error but it can usually be ignored or the error turned off in the wire shark settings.

Comment: Some NIC drivers allow you to turn off checksum offloading. Try this and retest the code

Comment: it resolved the header issue but the udp stands where it was before... even implemented tcp to no avail, the server wouldn't communicate just like in udp's case... but i think i should put up a new question for this...

Answer (score 1):

Most NICs will perform checksum validation and generation these days instead of the os network stack. This is to improve performance and is known as checksum offloading. As such wiresshark will report the fact the checksum is missing as an error but it can usually be ignored or the error turned off in the wire shark settings.

Some NIC drivers allow you to turn off checksum offloading. Try this and retest the code

Comment: ... this is a workaround, but here UDP packets are still badly formed... :( Is it not possible to set the UDP checksum in the UDP header before sending, at IdUDPServer level? No corresponding event at IdUDPServer level? UDP checksum is pretty basic (this is a simple 16 bit accumulation, AFAIR).

Comment: You'll have to fiddle in the source and make a hack class to expose the required method / field. I just did the workaround and didn't bother with the check-sum as I included it in my message packet.